# Modify elements based on data from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

So i've just started learning Angular JS and i'm having troubles to do something that should be really simple but I can't figure out how to do it. Here's my problem...

I have a Array of objects from which I display data using ng repeat.

```
 <div ng-repeat="computer in workbench.computers | orderBy:'computer.benchid'">
     <computer ng-show="tab.isSelected({{ computer.computer.benchid }}) || tab.isSelected(0)"></computer>
</div>
```

And inside the computer element I have an attribute that is `{{ computer.benchid }}` which I can display just fine.

Here is the Computer element:

```
<div class="widget col-lg-4">
<div class="widget-head br-green">
    <h3><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> <b>{{ computer.computer.make }} - </b> {{ computer.computer.benchid }}</h3>
</div>
<div class="widget-body">
    <p>Processor: {{ computer.computer.processor }}</p>
    <p>Ram: {{ computer.computer.ram }}</p>
    <p>Hard Drive: {{ computer.computer.hard_drive }}</p>
    <p>Serial Number: {{ computer.computer.serial_number }}</p>
    <p>Product Key: {{ computer.computer.windows_product_key }}</p>
    <p><b>Notes:</b></p>
    <p>{{ computer.computer.computer_notes }}</p>
</div>
<div class="widget-foot">
    <p> Last updated at...</p>
</div>
```

My problem is that `benchid` is an Integer from 1 to 10 and I want change the value to the name of the bench example with pseudocode:
`if benchid === 1 show: "Workbench #1"`
How would be the best approach to do it?

Here is my controller:

```
    app.controller('WorkbenchController', ['$http', function($http){
    var workbenches = this;
    workbenches.computers = [];
    // Request the computers
    // Each of them has an object that has a computer
    $http.get('/api/computer').success(function(data) {
        workbenches.computers = data.computers;
    });
}]);
```

EDIT:

The getWorkbenchName() function:

```
<script>
function getWorkbenchName(workbenchNumber) {
    switch(workbenchNumber) {
        case 1:
            return "Workbench #1";
        case 2:
            return "Workbench #2";
        case 3:
            return "Workbench #3";
        case 4:
            return "Workbench #4";
        case 5:
            return "Laptop Workbench";
        case 6:
            return "Bla's Desk";
        case 7:
            return "Bleh's Desk";
        case 8:
            return "Mac Workbench";
        case 9:
            return "Workroom Shelf";
        case 10:
            return "Finished Room";
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: `Workbench #{{ computer.computer.benchid }}` ? or is it that the descption wil be different? if so just add a function on the scope pass in benchid and get the actual description.. Or update the viewmodel to have the description as well..

Comment: That would work if all the workbench's are just that.. but by example workbench #10 is called "Finished Room", etc.. just Workbench 1-5 have the default names.
PSL I have a function in the scope that can return the right name. But

Comment: Where do you get the name from? from a service..? just do `<b>{{ computer.computer.make }} - </b> {{ getworkBenchName(computer.computer.benchid) }}` and attach the method `getworkBenchName` on the scope which takes the id and retunrs the desciption

Comment: I'm trying 2 approaches. 1- I have a function that is getWorkbenchName(number) and returns the right name. I also have an array with the names that I was trying to bind. But I can't get none of those to work because I don't know how to make the call to any of them.

Comment: It is withing the ng-repeat right? You can have your `<computer ng-show="tab.isSelected({{ computer.computer.benchid }}) || tab.isSelected(0)" workbenchname="getWorkbenchName("id")"></computer>` take a text argument.. and use `@` binding in your directive to bind it to your template. Your directive is isolated scope right?

Comment: oh one more thing.. You cannot just call a global function from within the view.. you need to attach `getWorkbenchName` to the scope to be able to access it. Are you using `controllerAs` syntax?

Comment: Here's my computer directive... https://gist.github.com/fnk0/bf65d1cd4ad1a033eba5

Comment: This is template, You don't have a directive definision?

Comment: Yes. Here's the directive https://gist.github.com/fnk0/c0b045ebb6b2d5c86a75

Comment: Ok then add in your controller `workbenches.getWorkbenchName= function(workbenchNumber){...` and in your template use `{{workbench.getWorkBenchName("benchId")}}`

Comment: Also remember that `return null` will display null on the screen, you might want to change it to an empty string or something

Comment: So i'm trying this now.. ```{{ workbench.getWorkbenchName(computer.computer.benchid) }}```

and here's the Workbench controller https://gist.github.com/fnk0/b3647bf64120d36dbb6f
but not is showing up now or non error is returned

Comment: Where is your ng-controller in the view? Are u using `controllerAs` syntax

Comment: the ng-controller is attached to the section in which <computer> is 
https://gist.github.com/fnk0/b8628e383493017e0e29

Comment: Did you verify if you are getting inside the method at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this seems like the kind of thing you could potentially use in various parts of your app, I wrote up [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tU0KZB4p5xHXRg8q9ZxU) to show how you could store the workbench names in a factory which then could be used throughout the app.

```
app.factory('WorkbenchNames', function(){
  var factory = this;
  factory.workbenches = {
    1:"Workbench #1",
    2:"Workbench #2",
    3:"Workbench #3",
    4:"Workbench #4",
    5:"Laptop Workbench",
    6:"Bla's Desk",
    7:"Bleh's Desk",
    8:"Mac Workbench",
    9:"Workroom Shelf",
    10:"Finished Room"
  };
  factory.getWorkbenchName = function(id){
    if(factory.workbenches[id])
      return factory.workbenches[id];
    else
      return 'Unknown Workbench'; // You could put a default here
  };
  return {
    workbenches: factory.workbenches,
    getWorkbenchName: factory.getWorkbenchName
  }

});
```

I bind a function in the controller to the function returned by the service to be able to call it from the UI.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'WorkbenchNames', function($scope, WorkbenchNames) {
  this.computers = [{id: 1, benchid: 1}, {id:2, benchid: 10}, {id: 13, benchid: 13}];
  this.getWorkbenchName = WorkbenchNames.getWorkbenchName;
}]);
```

And then can just call it inside a repeat

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
    <div ng-repeat="computer in main.computers">
        <b>{{computer.id}}</b>
        <br />
        <b>{{ main.getWorkbenchName(computer.benchid) }}</b>
        <br />
    </div>
</body>
```

I like this method because it pulls the definition out for use in other places in your code. It could also be refactored out and loaded from a datastore and then available for the whole life of your app.